# Problems importing Python libraries into PHP script

Tags: python, php, anaconda, miniconda, osmnx

When the script runs it goes up to

```
import networkx as nx
print ("networkx")
```

and just after doing that import it stops due to some error loading osmnx delete that import and the error persists with the remaining imports

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('C:\Users\juan_\.spyder-py3\distanceMatrixSc.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Python CODE (Error area)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Fri Oct  8 15:33:40 2021

@author: juan_
"""
print("Code starts")
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\python38.zip')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\DLLs')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages\\win32')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\juan_\\.ipython')
sys.path.append('C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python-gis\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\juan_\\.ipython')

import networkx as nx
print("networkx")
import osmnx as ox <--Here the code stops...
print("osmnx")
import geopandas as gpd
print("geopandas")
from shapely.geometry import Point
print("shapely.geometry")

print("Imports succes")
```

Comment: Could you add what the error is you are getting? Also, whay are you manually adding all those paths to `sys.path`? That looks like a source of problems when it comes to loading DLL files

Comment: The error was fixed when I switched to my server with Ubuntu operating system.

(And also remove the sys.paths)